# Change token for TokenAuthentication each time user logs in

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'd like to revoke the prior token each time a user logs in. That would mean generating a new token (or at least changing the key of existing model entity). It all sounds straightforward, but in the DRF docs, I don't see any mention of that scenario. The docs seem to assume that the token always stays the same. Is that just a simple case, or am I missing something? My question is: Is there something wrong with changing the token each time a user logs in?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `TokenAuthentication` provided by Django REST Framework is intended to be used for simple cases where the token never needs to change, and there is only a single token for a user.

> The docs seem to assume that the token always stays the same.

This is correct. Anything extra has to be implemented independently.

> I'd like to revoke the prior token each time a user logs in.

You can do this in the authentication view by removing any tokens for the user who is logged in.

```
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token

Token.objects.filter(user=the_user).delete()
```

If you are using the views provided for token authentication, then you will need to [subclass them](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/d109ae0a2e78551977d93e2507267e43a685fafd/rest_framework/authtoken/views.py) to always get a new token for the user.

```
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    throttle_classes = ()
    permission_classes = ()
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.JSONParser,)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)

    def post(self, request):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']

        Token.objects.filter(user=the_user).delete()
        token, created = Token.objects.create(user=user)

        return Response({'token': token.key})
```

This will always invalidate the previous key and generate a new key.

Comment: Thanks so much @kevin-brown. Great, clear, and thorough answer.

Comment: @Kevin Brown is it only my impression or for DRF there seems to be a lack of documentation and resources when it comes to SessionAuthentication for an API? Token authentication seems by far the most endorsed method with multiple third-party packages developed.

Comment: Thanks You, well this line
`token, created = Token.objects.create(user=user)`

should be changed to
`token = Token.objects.create(user=user)`