# Which authentication to be used when using Django Rest Framework and IOS app?

Tags: python, ios, django, django-rest-framework

I have an iOS app that uses an API powered by Django REST framework to store, update, fetch data from a database. I need to provide the two more following functionalities which stores the user data at the server:

1. Login with Email
2. Login with Facebook

There appears to be two different authentication systems that I can use:

1. [Django User Authentication System](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/)
2. [Django Rest Framework Authentication](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/)

How should I handle this in my API?

Comment: use Django Rest Framework Authentication

Comment: Thanks! DRF Authentication is pretty easy then Django User Authentication. Easy to learn :)

Answer (score 17):

When you are using Django REST framework with iOS, unless you are using a browser, the standard Django authentication system is out of the question. This is exposed through the [DRF authentication system as `SessionAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) and it relies on your application being able to transfer cookies and the CSRF token with the request, which typically isn't possible.

**In most situations** where you are using the Django authentication system already, and you can trust your app storing passwords, you would [use something like `BasicAuthentiction`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#basicauthentication). Most people can't though, or they don't trust their application ecosystem, so they use a token-based authentication system [like `TokenAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#tokenauthentication) or [`OAuth2Authorization`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#oauth2authentication) (in combination [with an OAuth provider](https://github.com/caffeinehit/django-oauth2-provider)). You can read more about each authentication type [in this answer on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582256/359284).

**But in your situation**, you are basically restricted to just using **something like OAuth 2**. This is because you need to associate a user with a token, and most authentication systems require you to provide a username and password. For social accounts, this usually isn't the case, and they would not normally be able to log in. OAuth 2 works in combination with the standard Django login, so you are not restricted to just a username and password. I've written more about how this works in [this detailed Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27051810/359284).