# How to implement an iOS app which can share post to Facebook and get friends post to iOS app

Tags: python, ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

I have an app which has Facebook integration for login purpose. In my app we can add item.
Now here is the features which I want to add to my app.

1. I want to post that item directly to Facebook wall.
2. My Facebook friends can see my post from an iOS app which I had posted from my app.

I didn't got the proper way to implement this features. 
For e.g.- It should be like Instagram where we can see our post and others friends post.

I am using graph api for Facebook login.
If anyone knows then it should be very thankful to me.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Which authentication to be used when using Django Rest Framework and IOS app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27997483/which-authentication-to-be-used-when-using-django-rest-framework-and-ios-app)

Comment: No it is not similar to that @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I simply needs to post and get post from Facebook using web services.

Comment: This question is also **too broad** and **primarily opinion-based**. You **haven't even told what would you do**, you are only asking for people's opinions.

Comment: I will explain it again @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH. I want to use graph api for sharing and fetching the post. How can I do that with web services

Comment: Not here, please take some time to edit your question (be explicit and detailed) to avoid been flagged. I'm just trying to help you :)

Comment: ok thank for your guidance @AndrésPérez-AlbelaH.