# django rest framework Token authentication with expiring token

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, http-token-authentication

I am creating a django api system that works with django rest framework. I need an expiring token system that works on the below manner

We have three user roles

- admin (token expire in 1 hour)
- supervisor (token expire in 1 hour)
- end user (token expire in 6 months)

i saw many third party add ons but that doesn't completely match my requirements

does any one find a package that can be tweaked or directly used to match my requirements?

Thanks
Akhil

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Do you really need to login admin the same approach as users? Maybe you can login with admin on admin-panel with session and cookie authentication instead of token and keep token for normal users

Comment: [You probably don't want `TokenAuthentication`.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27578726/359284)