# django-rest-framework Token Auth and logout

Tags: authentication, token, django-rest-framework

As far as understood, `obtain_auth_token` view works as a login functionality. You provide credentials and get the token back. What will be the logout? Should I delete the token on logout? What would be the best practice?

If deleting is OK, then how do I handle multiple clients at the same time. Say, the user logs out from mobile device but wants to stay logged in on the web. The `Token` model currently has a **OneToOne** relationship to `User`.

Please give me some advice. Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `TokenAuthentication` provided by Django REST framework is intended to be used as a very *simple token* authentication. What I mean by that is, you get

- A simple token that ties an API consumer to a user
- ...that [doesn't rotate by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27570952/359284)
- ...that [doesn't expire by default](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14567586/359284)
- ...that is shared between API consumers (single token)

If you are looking for anything more advanced than that, you usually have to look into a different token authentication method. This can be as simple as subclassing the standard `TokenAuthentication` classes and views (as linked), but the `Token` model is not easily swappable. This means that changing the `user` field to a `ForeignKey`, allowing you to have multiple tokens for a user, is not easy to implement.

Luckily, Django REST framework [does support other authentication methods](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/), such as OAuth and JSON Web Tokens, both of which support multiple tokens for users. You can find a comparison of the common authentication classes [at this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27582256/359284).

Comment: Thanks. Initially I was thinking about extending the token but now that you said it's not trivial I'll give [django-rest-framework-jwt](https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt) a try. It looks promising.